GNU parallel stalls
I have an algorithm, implemented in Java, which needs to be evaluated on a large set of benchmark instances. To make the benchmarking more efficiently, I use gnu parallel to run multiple instances consecutively on a linux server:
/usr/bin/printf "%s\n" "${instances[@]}" | parallel --no-notice -P 4 -k --eta --colsep ' ' "java -Xmx15g -cp ./target/FSVRPpd-1.0.jar fvrpsd.main.Main {} 2>&1" >> $outputfile
The algorithm is both CPU and memory intensive. Initially, as expected, the command above kicks off 4 parallel processes. Looking at the output of top, I can clearly see 4 java processes each requiring 100% cpu. Collectively, these 4 processes start grinding through the list of instances. Oddly, after a while, I see those processes 'die out'. They reduce to 0.1% CPU, with a tiny bit of memory, as if they are idling. Invoking strace on one of those processes gives:
strace -p 14235
strace: Process 14235 attached
futex(0x7f346c0459d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 14236, NULL) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)

After a while, only 1 process remains busy, and even that process, while it consumes a significant amount of memory and cpu, no longer seems to make progress towards solving new instances.
I can't seem to tell what's going on:

Running the instances sequentially seems to work fine, but takes a very long time
Running the same command with -Xmx60g also seems to solve the problem, i.e. I can actually get through the entire list of instances, but occasionally, the OOM-killer kills a process. While this works, it's undesirable as I'd rather have an OOM exception which I can catch and properly handle.

The Java algorithm itself is in essence a search algorithm, that occasionally invokes a C++ library through JNI. Moreover, some logging is performed using logback. Other than that there's nothing special (e.g. no database or network read/writes that could be blocking).
I'm not quite sure how to even start troubleshooting this issue.

You probably have bad error handling when competing for a resource or running out of memory. Run in debug mode, attach a debugger, tell it to break on uncaught exceptions, and let the code run. Even if not stopping you will be able to see if everything is fine.

If running only one JVM works couldn't you do the parallelization in the JVM, e.g. by feeding multiple tasks to a task pool? That of course would require the implementation to be thread-safe, e.g. not using global variables for state etc.

Does it work if you run 1 at a time: -j1 If so: How about 2 or 3?
Does it work if you run 4 in parallel outside GNU Parallel:
java -Xmx15g -cp ./target/FSVRPpd-1.0.jar fvrpsd.main.Main foo 2>&1 &
java -Xmx15g -cp ./target/FSVRPpd-1.0.jar fvrpsd.main.Main bar 2>&1 &
java -Xmx15g -cp ./target/FSVRPpd-1.0.jar fvrpsd.main.Main baz 2>&1 &
java -Xmx15g -cp ./target/FSVRPpd-1.0.jar fvrpsd.main.Main quux 2>&1 &

Some programs need a terminal: -o
